# How do I find the URL of the Google Sheets that queried my Data Warehouse?

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, url, google-bigquery, information-schema

I'm working on a some refactoring projects and in order to trace dependencies and prevent downstream turmoil, I'm looking for a clean way to identify the URLs of the Google Sheets which query Bigquery.

The connection data helps me see that the queries are coming from Google Sheets, but I'm not able to get down to the file/URL level.

Any tips for where this data might live in the INFORMATION SCHEMA or elsewhere?

Comment: No one? There must be a way.